# How can I iterate over a packed variadic template argument list?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm trying to find a method to iterate over an a pack variadic template argument list.
Now as with all iterations, you need some sort of method of knowing how many arguments are in the packed list, and more importantly how to individually get data from a packed argument list.

The general idea is to iterate over the list, store all data of type int into a vector, store all data of type char* into a vector, and store all data of type float, into a vector. During this process there also needs to be a seperate vector that stores individual chars of what order the arguments went in.  As an example, when you push_back(a_float), you're also doing a push_back('f') which is simply storing an individual char to know the order of the data.  I could also use a std::string here and simply use +=.  The vector was just used as an example.

Now the way the thing is designed is the function itself is constructed using a macro, despite the evil intentions, it's required, as this is an experiment.  So it's literally impossible to use a recursive call, since the actual implementation that will house all this will be expanded at compile time; and you cannot recruse a macro.

Despite all possible attempts, I'm still stuck at figuring out how to actually do this.  So instead I'm using a more convoluted method that involves constructing a type, and passing that type into the varadic template, expanding it inside a vector and then simply iterating that.  However I do not want to have to call the function like:

```
foo(arg(1), arg(2.0f), arg("three");
```

So the real question is how can I do without such?  To give you guys a better understanding of what the code is actually doing, I've pasted the optimistic approach that I'm currently using.

```
struct any {
  void do_i(int   e) { INT    = e; }
  void do_f(float e) { FLOAT  = e; }
  void do_s(char* e) { STRING = e; }

  int   INT;
  float FLOAT;
  char *STRING;
};


template<typename T> struct get        { T      operator()(const any& t) { return T();      } };
template<>           struct get<int>   { int    operator()(const any& t) { return t.INT;    } };
template<>           struct get<float> { float  operator()(const any& t) { return t.FLOAT;  } };
template<>           struct get<char*> { char*  operator()(const any& t) { return t.STRING; } };

#define def(name)                                  \
  template<typename... T>                          \
  auto name (T... argv) -> any {                   \
   std::initializer_list<any> argin = { argv... }; \
    std::vector<any> args = argin;
#define get(name,T)  get<T>()(args[name])
#define end }

any arg(int   a) { any arg; arg.INT    = a; return arg; }
any arg(float f) { any arg; arg.FLOAT  = f; return arg; }
any arg(char* s) { any arg; arg.STRING = s; return arg; }
```

I know this is nasty, however it's a pure experiment, and will not be used in production code.  It's purely an idea.  It could probably be done a better way.  But an example of how you would use this system:

```
def(foo)
  int data = get(0, int);
  std::cout << data << std::endl;
end
```

looks a lot like python. it works too, but the only problem is how you call this function.
Heres a quick example:

```
foo(arg(1000));
```

I'm required to construct a new any type, which is highly aesthetic, but thats not to say those macros are not either.  Aside the point, I just want to the option of doing:
    foo(1000);

I know it can be done, I just need some sort of iteration method, or more importantly some std::get method for packed variadic template argument lists.  Which I'm sure can be done.

Also to note, I'm well aware that this is not exactly type friendly, as I'm only supporting int,float,char* and thats okay with me.  I'm not requiring anything else, and I'll add checks to use type_traits to validate that the arguments passed are indeed the correct ones to produce a compile time error if data is incorrect.  This is purely not an issue.  I also don't need support for anything other then these POD types.

It would be highly apprecaited if I could get some constructive help, opposed to arguments about my purely illogical and stupid use of macros and POD only types.  I'm well aware of how fragile and broken the code is.  This is merley an experiment, and I can later rectify issues with non-POD data, and make it more type-safe and useable.

Thanks for your undertstanding, and I'm looking forward to help.

Comment: It looks a bit like you might use `boost::variant<int, float, std::string>` instead. That would only allow storing one value per "any" at a time, though, and provide means to check the type of the stored value.

Comment: I don't want to use boost.  As much as others seem to like the extensive amount of support it offers, I'm just trying to stick with what's supported in the standard library.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you want to wrap arguments to `any`, you can use the following setup. I also made the `any` class a bit more usable, although it isn't technically an `any` class.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct any {
  enum type {Int, Float, String};
  any(int   e) { m_data.INT    = e; m_type = Int;}
  any(float e) { m_data.FLOAT  = e; m_type = Float;}
  any(char* e) { m_data.STRING = e; m_type = String;}
  type get_type() const { return m_type; }
  int get_int() const { return m_data.INT; }
  float get_float() const { return m_data.FLOAT; }
  char* get_string() const { return m_data.STRING; }
private:
  type m_type;
  union {
    int   INT;
    float FLOAT;
    char *STRING;
  } m_data;
};

template <class ...Args>
void foo_imp(const Args&... args)
{
    std::vector<any> vec = {args...};
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
        switch (vec[i].get_type()) {
            case any::Int: std::cout << vec[i].get_int() << '\n'; break;
            case any::Float: std::cout << vec[i].get_float() << '\n'; break;
            case any::String: std::cout << vec[i].get_string() << '\n'; break;
        }
    }
}

template <class ...Args>
void foo(Args... args)
{
    foo_imp(any(args)...);  //pass each arg to any constructor, and call foo_imp with resulting any objects
}

int main()
{
    char s[] = "Hello";
    foo(1, 3.4f, s);
}
```

It is however possible to write functions to access the nth argument in a variadic template function and to apply a function to each argument, which might be a better way of doing whatever you want to achieve.

Comment: This is actually neat, and is actually what I was looking for, I could modify this to be usable.

Comment: I tried using `std::vector<any> vec = {args...};` inside a lambda function - I wanted to handle arguments like in your example, however it would not compile - do you know if this expression is only for template functions ?

Comment: typedef boost::variant<int, float, std::string> Variant; -  it seems inside lambda using this instead of any class, then it works

Answer (score 62):

If your inputs are all of the same type, see `OMGtechy`'s great answer.

For mixed-types we can use [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) (introduced in `c++17`) with a callable (in this case, a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)):

```
#include <iostream>

template <class ... Ts>
void Foo (Ts && ... inputs)
{
    int i = 0;

    ([&]
    {
        // Do things in your "loop" lambda

        ++i;
        std::cout << "input " << i << " = " << inputs << std::endl;

    } (), ...);
}

int main ()
{
    Foo(2, 3, 4u, (int64_t) 9, 'a', 2.3);
}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Erv61TTbb)

(Thanks to [glades](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11770390/glades) for pointing out in the comments that I didn't need to explicitly pass `inputs` to the lambda. This made it a lot neater.)

---

If you need `return`/`break`s in your loop, here are some workarounds:

- [Demo using try/throw](https://godbolt.org/z/xKo5j47he). Note that `throw`s [can cause tremendous slow down](https://youtu.be/GC4cp4U2f2E?t=1512) of this function; so only use this option if speed isn't important, or the `break`/`return`s are genuinely *exceptional*.
- [Demo using variable/if switches](https://godbolt.org/z/jj4M3M65q).

These latter answers are honestly a code smell, but shows it's general-purpose.

Comment: This is really neat, compact, and understandable!

Comment: If you have issue trying to understand lambda syntax in this context, here is what it means: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68872572/lambda-call-operator-and-parenthesized-lambda/68872590#68872590

Comment: For slightly better readability, I would suggest defining the lambda outside the fold expression. `auto processOne = [&]() { ... }; (processOne(multi_inputs), ...);` might be slightly easier to parse for any less template-affine colleagues of yours, and you can comment it more easily: https://godbolt.org/z/4GhrGPqbT

Comment: You don't even need to pass the parameter pack to the template, you can just use multi_inputs straight in the lambda body

Comment: @Elliott: C++ works in mysterious ways: https://godbolt.org/z/xWqnjn11M

Comment: What sorcery is this! Such an odd syntax!

Comment: Strange thing, if we declare `i` inside the lambda as `static`, then the `++i;` instruction seems to be ignored since `i` doesn't get incremented: https://godbolt.org/z/635o7sKs8

Comment: @Fareanor, I think that's because `([&]{ static int i = 0; ++i; /*stuff*/ }(), ...)` expands to `[&]{ static int i = 0, ++i; /*stuff for first arg*/ }(); [&]{ static int i = 0, ++i; /*stuff for second arg*/ }()`and so on. [See what happens if you re-use the lambda instead](https://godbolt.org/z/qsKxEdPYr).

Answer (score 41):

Range based for loops are wonderful:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <any>

template <typename... Things>
void printVariadic(Things... things) {
    for(const auto p : {things...}) {
        std::cout << p.type().name() << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    printVariadic(std::any(42), std::any('?'), std::any("C++"));
}
```

For me, [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a04e4f4863f7cd70) produces the output:

```
i
c
PKc
```

[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5cc4e21c2de8bd6)'s an example without `std::any`, which might be easier to understand for those not familiar with `std::type_info`:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename... Things>
void printVariadic(Things... things) {
    for(const auto p : {things...}) {
        std::cout << p << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    printVariadic(1, 2, 3);
}
```

As you might expect, this produces:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: This only works because the compiler can optimize your homogeneous initializer list.  This wouldn't work in all cases.

Comment: @Anthony, yes, I see that this doesn't work with mixed-type inputs, which is a real shame...

Answer (score 27):

You can create a container of it by initializing it with your parameter pack between {}. As long as the type of params... is homogeneous or at least convertable to the element type of your container, it will work. (tested with g++ 4.6.1)

```
#include <array>

template <class... Params>
void f(Params... params) {
    std::array<int, sizeof...(params)> list = {params...};
}
```

Comment: Welcome on SO, it is a good idea to post fully compiling example. As the solution might be obvious for you, some people here are new to some languages and it won't be that obvious for them. :) I also suggest that you have a look to our FAQ :  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: It is also possible to support heterogeneous types using std::tuple, such as in this answer [http://stackoverflow.com/a/15139244/2607949](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15139244/2607949)

Comment: is this cheap? looks cheap to me.

Answer (score 27):

There is no specific feature for it right now but there are some workarounds you can use.

## Using initialization list

One workaround uses the fact, that subexpressions of [initialization lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) are evaluated in order. `int a[] = {get1(), get2()}` will execute `get1` before executing `get2`. Maybe [fold expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) will come handy for similar techniques in the future. To call `do()` on every argument, you can do something like this:

```
template <class... Args>
void doSomething(Args... args) {
    int x[] = {args.do()...};
}
```

However, this will only work when `do()` is returning an `int`. You can use the [comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) to support operations which do not return a proper value.

```
template <class... Args>
void doSomething(Args... args) {
    int x[] = {(args.do(), 0)...};
}
```

To do more complex things, you can put them in another function:

```
template <class Arg>
void process(Arg arg, int &someOtherData) {
    // You can do something with arg here.
}

template <class... Args>
void doSomething(Args... args) {
    int someOtherData;
    int x[] = {(process(args, someOtherData), 0)...};
}
```

Note that with generic [lambdas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) (C++14), you can define a function to do this boilerplate for you.

```
template <class F, class... Args>
void do_for(F f, Args... args) {
    int x[] = {(f(args), 0)...};
}

template <class... Args>
void doSomething(Args... args) {
    do_for([&](auto arg) {
        // You can do something with arg here.
    }, args...);
}
```

## Using recursion

Another possibility is to use recursion. Here is a small example that defines a similar function `do_for` as above.

```
template <class F, class First, class... Rest>
void do_for(F f, First first, Rest... rest) {
    f(first);
    do_for(f, rest...);
}
template <class F>
void do_for(F f) {
    // Parameter pack is empty.
}

template <class... Args>
void doSomething(Args... args) {
    do_for([&](auto arg) {
        // You can do something with arg here.
    }, args...);
}
```

Comment: The array version does not work if the parameter pack is empty.

Answer (score 23):

This is not how one would typically use Variadic templates, not at all.

Iterations over a variadic pack is not possible, as per the language rules, so you need to turn toward recursion.

```
class Stock
{
public:
  bool isInt(size_t i) { return _indexes.at(i).first == Int; }
  int getInt(size_t i) { assert(isInt(i)); return _ints.at(_indexes.at(i).second); }

  // push (a)
  template <typename... Args>
  void push(int i, Args... args) {
    _indexes.push_back(std::make_pair(Int, _ints.size()));
    _ints.push_back(i);
    this->push(args...);
  }

  // push (b)
  template <typename... Args>
  void push(float f, Args... args) {
    _indexes.push_back(std::make_pair(Float, _floats.size()));
    _floats.push_back(f);
    this->push(args...);
  }

private:
  // push (c)
  void push() {}

  enum Type { Int, Float; };
  typedef size_t Index;

  std::vector<std::pair<Type,Index>> _indexes;
  std::vector<int> _ints;
  std::vector<float> _floats;
};
```

Example (in action), suppose we have `Stock stock;`:

- `stock.push(1, 3.2f, 4, 5, 4.2f);` is resolved to (a) as the first argument is an `int`
- `this->push(args...)` is expanded to `this->push(3.2f, 4, 5, 4.2f);`, which is resolved to (b) as the first argument is a `float`
- `this->push(args...)` is expanded to `this->push(4, 5, 4.2f);`, which is resolved to (a) as the first argument is an `int`
- `this->push(args...)` is expanded to `this->push(5, 4.2f);`, which is resolved to (a) as the first argument is an `int`
- `this->push(args...)` is expanded to `this->push(4.2f);`, which is resolved to (b) as the first argument is a `float`
- `this->push(args...)` is expanded to `this->push();`, which is resolved to (c) as there is no argument, thus ending the recursion

Thus:

- Adding another type to handle is as simple as adding another overload, changing the first type (for example, `std::string const&`)
- If a completely different type is passed (say `Foo`), then no overload can be selected, resulting in a compile-time error.

One caveat: Automatic conversion means a `double` would select overload (b) and a `short` would select overload (a). If this is not desired, then SFINAE need be introduced which makes the method slightly more complicated (well, their signatures at least), example:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
typename std::enable_if<is_int<T>::value>::type push(T i, Args... args);
```

Where `is_int` would be something like:

```
template <typename T> struct is_int { static bool constexpr value = false; };
template <> struct is_int<int> { static bool constexpr value = true; };
```

---

Another alternative, though, would be to consider a variant type. For example:

```
typedef boost::variant<int, float, std::string> Variant;
```

It exists already, with all utilities, it can be stored in a `vector`, copied, etc... and seems really much like what you need, even though it does not use Variadic Templates.

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for, since this only lets me push(a_bunch_of_ints); or push(a_bunch_of_floats); what I'm relling looking for is push(a_bunch_of_ints_and_floats_in_any_order);

Comment: @graphitemaster: I am afraid you did not understand how variadic template (or overload resolution) works. I have updated with an example to show that *it does* work as you intended.

Answer (score 4):

You can't iterate, but you can recurse over the list.  Check the printf() example on wikipedia:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x#Variadic_templates

Comment: Yes I understand, but I still need a method of knowing the order in which this occurs, and have the option of reconstructing the data in the same order it was put in.

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple variadic templates, this is a bit messy, but it works and is easy to understand.
You simply have a function with the variadic template like so:

```
template <typename ...ArgsType >
void function(ArgsType... Args){
     helperFunction(Args...);
}
```

And a helper function like so:

```
void helperFunction() {}

template <typename T, typename ...ArgsType >
void helperFunction(T t, ArgsType... Args) {

     //do what you want with t
    function(Args...);

}
```

Now when you call "function" the "helperFunction" will be called and isolate the first passed parameter from the rest, this variable can b used to call another function (or something). Then "function" will be called again and again until there are no more variables left. Note you might have to declare helperClass before "function".

The final code will look like this:

```
void helperFunction();

template <typename T, typename ...ArgsType >
void helperFunction(T t, ArgsType... Args);

template <typename ...ArgsType >
void function(ArgsType... Args){
     helperFunction(Args...);
}

void helperFunction() {}

template <typename T, typename ...ArgsType >
void helperFunction(T t, ArgsType... Args) {

     //do what you want with t
    function(Args...);

}
```

The code is not tested.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>    

template <typename Fun>
void iteratePack(const Fun&) {}

template <typename Fun, typename Arg, typename ... Args>
void iteratePack(const Fun &fun, Arg &&arg, Args&& ... args)
{
    fun(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
    iteratePack(fun, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <typename ... Args>
void test(const Args& ... args)
{
    iteratePack([&](auto &arg)
    {
        std::cout << arg << std::endl;
    },
    args...);
}

int main()
{
    test(20, "hello", 40);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
20
hello
40
```

Answer (score -1):

I used this to get it working with multiple different class types. this way you can have an abstract class and I will accept any of its subclasses

```cpp
template <class... SubClasses>
void foo(const SubClasses&... subClasses){
    static_assert((std::is_base_of_v<BaseClass, SubClasses> && ...), "check if members are subclasses of a BaseClass");
    for(const BaseClass* class : std::initializer_list<BaseClass *>{&subClasses...}) {
        class->doSomething();
    }
}
```