# How to store variadic arguments in a fixed type tuple?

Tags: visual-c++, tuples, variadic-templates

I know the types of the variadic arguments so I am trying to store them in a pre-defined `tuple`.

Here is my code:

```
class data
{
public:
    std::tuple<unsigned long long, char, unsigned short, bool, unsigned int, int, float, double, std::string> tpl;
};

data d;

template<typename...Args>
void func(Args...args)
{
    // stores the arguments in d.tpl
}

int main()
{
    func(234, 'g', 34.8f, "Hello World!");
}
```

Comment: Related? [How can I iterate over a packed variadic template argument list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7230621/10871073)

Comment: I'm trying to store variadic arguments of known type to a tuple, so that doesn't really help.

Comment: Hmm. I was thinking of posting an answer but it would be *extremely* similar to the answer given on the linked question - the one using the `std::any` type.

Comment: You might be looking for `((std::get<Args>(d.tpl) = args), ...);` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4faoMbPqx). Except that you are passing a `const char*` to `func`, but the tuple doesn't have an element of type `const char*`.

Comment: For some reason though, there are gaps between some of the elements.