# C++ Variadic Template: Construct a list of class members

Tags: c++, reflection, variadic-templates

I would like to create class members through a variadic template so that a template defined like this:

```
template<typename firstType, firstName, Rest... rest>
class MyClass{
    FirstType firstName;
    //do something recursvy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230621/how-can-i-iterate-over-a-packed-variadic-template-argument-list
};
```

with the following instance:

```
class MyClass<int A, float B, char c>
```

would generate a class like this:

```
class MyClass{
    int A;
    float B;
    char c;
}
```

How do I do this? or something equivalent like a tuple.

I can only picture doing this with nasty C macros.

Comment: If you want the nested type names to match the template parameter names, it can't be done with standard C++ afaik. What's your use case? What's wrong with `std::tuple`?

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with tuple?

Comment: Judging from your question alone, it seems like you want `MyClass` to be a compound of several types passed as template arguments. `std::tuple` is just that. So is there anything you want to achieve, that you can't with `std::tuple`?

Comment: String based name access without string comparison. I guess I might be able to build an enum with the template parameters